# how to delete particular images from folder using exception handling in python3

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5

I have 500 images in a folder. I want to delete unreadable images using exception handling in python.

When i am using :

```
os.remove()
```

then I am getting an error message :

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '-coast-ocean-horizon-sky-sunrise-sunset-dawn-atmosphere-plane-dusk-vehicle-flight-island-yellow-shadows-colors-holidays-hot-reflections-the-mediterranean-sea-sunset-sun-aegean-sea-atmosphere-of-earth-484653.jpg' "
```

since this

```
-coast-ocean-horizon-sky-sunrise-sunset-dawn-atmosphere-plane-dusk-vehicle-flight-island-yellow-shadows-colors-holidays-hot-reflections-the-mediterranean-sea-sunset-sun-aegean-sea-atmosphere-of-earth-484653.jpg')
```

is the first image that is unreadable when iterating over the loop, how do I solve it?

Comment: When deleting you have to pass the entire path of the image file not the image file alone

Comment: The images and the .exe file should be in the same folder else pass the entire path of the image.